# How to test a route using CamelJmsDestinationName?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, apache-camel

I have a processor where I'm using the CamelJmsDestinationName header to dynamically determine to destination in one of my routes (details [here](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html)).

So in my processor I'm setting the header

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelJmsDestinationName",messageExport.getEndpoint());
```

Then in my route, I have the following clause

```
.when(header("CamelJmsDestinationName").isNotNull())
   //Set to dummy, actual queue name will be set by processor (CamelJmsDestinationName)
   .to("activemq:queue:dummy")
.otherwise()
   .to("{{message.export.no_type_match}}")
   .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Message could not be matched to an existing route");
```

This works exactly as I expect. However I'm struggling with writing unit test for this route.
How can I test that the message ends up in whatever value I set for CamelJmsDestinationName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the easiest approach is to use a property for the "activemq:queue:" part and set it to "mock:activemq" in your testing.

```
.when(header("CamelJmsDestinationName").isNotNull())
   //Set to dummy, actual queue name will be set by processor (CamelJmsDestinationName)
   .to("{{activemq.endpoint}}:dummy")
.otherwise()
   .to("{{message.export.no_type_match}}")
   .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Message could not be matched to an existing route");
```

And then you can write tests where "activemq.endpoint" property is "mock", therefore you can test versus mock endpoints named `mock:dummy`, etc.

There is another approach where you can write a mock version of the activemq component, but it is more involved.

Comment: I think this would only solve part of the problem. While this approach would test that the actual routing works, it would not test that the value CamelJmsDestinationName is correctly populated to in the destination instead of dummy. But when I think about it, the specific logic is part of the Camel framework, and perhaps nothing that I should test in my own unit tests...

Comment: That part of the testing sounds more suited to a unit test on the processor, would that work? Otherwise if the list of possibel destinations is somewhat static you could always set up mock endpoints `mock:endpoint1`, `mock:endpoint2` and test that the right ones get hit.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably making this more difficult than it is :-) Thanks!